# solve $\int_0^{2} x^{2}\ e^{x^2} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_0^{2} x^{2}\ e^{x^2} dx$$

I tried using integral by parts: $u=x$ , $dv= e^{x^2}dx$ but the answer is: $ \frac{1}{2}xe^{x^2}$- $\frac{1}{2}\int e^{x^2}dx$ and I cant calculate $\int e^{x^2}dx$

Comment: That can't be done with "elementary" functions. One needs the error function (on the complex plane).

Comment: it is weird because we are not familiar with complex plane in university

Comment: Any chance there is a typo and it's $\int x e^{x^2} \mathrm dx$ instead?

Comment: Or $\int x^3e^{x^2}dx$ for that matter?

Comment: maybe he means that

Comment: Numerical methods suggest $\int_0^{2} e^{x^2} dx\approx 16.45263$  and $\int_0^{2} x^{2}\ e^{x^2} dx \approx 46.37184$.  Meanwhile $\operatorname{erfi}(2) = 18.5648024145755525987\ldots$

Comment: Your integral by parts may be missing a factor of $\frac12$

Comment: yes true i missed 1/2

Comment: @Soheil0098 could you please correct the answer obtained with integration by parts?

Comment: i did correct it

Comment: @Soheil0098 nevermind, the page just updated for me

Comment: haha it is a little hard for me using math jax

Comment: @Soheil0098 is the answer to the given question supposed to be $0$?

Comment: I dont know the answer it seems  there is a typo but why the answer should be 0?

Answer (score 2):

The [imaginary error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Imaginary_error_function) $\operatorname{erfi}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^xe^{t^2}dt$ satisfies $\int_0^2e^{ax^2}dx=\frac12\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\operatorname{erfi}(\sqrt{a})$, which you can differentiate with respect to $a$ to obtain$$\int_0^2x^2e^{ax^2}dx=\frac{2e^a-2\sqrt{\pi}\operatorname{erfi}(\sqrt{a})}{4a^{3/2}}.$$Hence $\int_0^2x^2e^{x^2}dx=\frac{2e-2\sqrt{\pi}\operatorname{erfi}(1)}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2e^{x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+2}}{n!}$$

So $$\int_0^2x^2 e^{x^2}dx=\int_0^2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+2}}{n!}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^2\frac{x^{2n+2}}{n!}dx$$ $$=8\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{4^n}{n!(2n+3)}$$

The integral and summation can be interchanged by uniform convergence of the series on the interval $[0,2]$